# Why Shodasha occupies special place in hindu worship?

Tags: numbers, numerology

Quite often we see  shodasha or no.16 is given high importance why?  Right from Shodasha samskara. Shodasha upachara pooja. Shodashi mantra. Shodashi  upasane of Lord as specified in satprashno upanishad. Is this all related in any way? What is its significance. Please brief or give reference for each Shodsha samskara, Shodash upachara pooja and Shodashi upasane of lord in satprashno upanishad and then specify what is 16th step that is connecting all? Even though by Guess we can see its Mukhyprana tattva or Vayu which is jiva kala abhimani in 16th step through which only completes all samshkara, pooja and upasane. but want to know from experts and any scriptual basis for this mukhyaprana or Vayu tattva reference.

Comment: Nice Q. What do we mean by mukhya kala abhimani and vayu tattva?

Comment: As per shanti mantra of taytrioupanishad Shanti mantra namaste tvamave prathaksham brahmasi.. How one would know about the presence Jiva inside body in most sutle manner without touching is life breath which indicates presence of Jiva and hence lord inside body.. The lord of life breath through jiva can be know is Hanuman or vayu. by transitive dependency lifebreath->lord->human->jiva (lord of jiva is hanuman) that is jiva kala abhimani devataha vayu deva @Archit

Comment: A little simpler please

Comment: Then u need to know what is shodhasha kala purusha from shatprashno upanishat inthat the 16th one is jiva please read the below answer @Archit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sixteen part Upasena of Lord as per shat prasnoupanishad.

1. 5 karma indriya (ear, eyes, nose, mouth and hand)
2. 5 gnana indriya (sound, form, smell, taste and touch)
3. manas (mind)
4. buddhi (intellect)
5. Ahamkara (Ego)
6. chita  (memory shell)
7. nama   (ones name or identiy)
8. Chetana or Jiva whose abhimani devata is mukhya prana or hanuman (16th part)

All 1-7 fifteen boundries needed to be crossed to reach Jiva or Soul. for that we need blessing of mukhya prana that jiva kala abhimani devatha and also we have the final distination of lakshmi narayana (17 and 18)

Shodha upachara pooja

https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-Shodashopachara-Puja

1. Avahanam- extend invitation,
2. Asanam- offer seat and ensure God is seated,
3. Paadyam- washing God’s feet,
4. Argyam- offering water,
5. Achamanam- self purification to attend God
6. Snanan- offering bath to God,
7. Yagnopavitham- offering the sacred thread,
8. Vastram- offering clothing,
9. Gandham- offering sandalwood paste,
10. Pushpam- offering flowers,
11. Dhoopam- offering insence as agar-bathis/doopam
12. Deepam- traditional oil lamp: bearing: ⊙-1-5-3 symbols,
13. Naivedyam- offering food,
14. Tamboolam- offering pan, supari with edible-camphor,
15. Neeranjanam- Mangala-harati, in clock-wise move and Namaskaram, ‘
16. Visarjanam- Respectfully bidding farewell by immersion in water bodies

https://www.amritapuri.org/1967/16samskaras.aum

1. Garbhadana Samskara – is performed by a married couple when conceiving a child. This important Samskara raises the act of conception to a sacred occasion, and is powerfully purifying and uplifting for the unborn child.
2. Pumsavana Samskara – is usually performed between the second and fourth month of pregnancy. Its purpose is: to insure the good health of the foetus and the proper formation of its organs, so that the family line and tradition will perpetuate thorugh the baby.
3. Simantonoyana Samskara – In the fourth or fifth month of pregnancy, the mind of the foetus begins to develop. This is when simantonoyana Samskara is performed. Its purpose is to protect the foetus–especially its newly forming mind–from all negative influences, and also to stimulate the development of the unborn child’s intellect.
4. Jatakarma Samskara is the ritual performed at the birth of a child noting the birth time and star and thus create a birth chart which is suppose to be the blue print of ones life.
5. Namakarana Samskara – On the eleventh day after the child’s birth, namakarana Samskara is performed. In this ceremony, the child receives its name.
6. Nishkramana Samskara – The baby’s first outing into the world, beyond the confines of the home.
7. Annaprashana – The first feeding of solid food to the baby, usually in the sixth month after birth.
8. Karnavedha Samskara – usually performed in the sixth or seventh month after birth, consists of the piercing of the baby’s ear lobes, so earrings may be worn.
9. Chudakarana Samskara – At the end of the first year after birth, or during the third year, the child’s hair is shaved–all but a tuft on the top of the head. This ritual shaving of hair, performed with ceremony, prayers, and chanting of Vedic hymns, is chudakarana Samskara This Samskara is for both boys and girls.
10. Vidyarambha Samskara – begins a student’s primary education by ceremonially introducing the child to the alphabet.
11. Upanayana Samskara – initiates the formal study of the Vedas. It is one of the most important and esteemed of the samskaras. Upon performance of Upanayana, a boy traditionally moves from home to live in the ashram of the guru.
12. Samavartana Samskara – With samavartana Samskara the disciple graduates from his Vedic studies and returns from the house of his guru. Thereafter, the disciple will marry and raise a family, and so enter the stage of householder, grihasthashrama.
13. Vivaha Samskara – The traditional Hindu wedding ceremony is known as vivaha Samskara It is considered by many to be the most important of all the samskaras.
14. Panchamahayagna Samskara – A married couple performs the panchamahayajna, or five great sacrifices, daily. In this Samskara, one honours, in turn, the rishis, the gods, the parents, humankind, and all created beings.
15. Vanaprastha Samskara – According to the Vedic tradition, vanaprastha is the third stage of life, following brahmacharya (Vedic student/disciple) and grihasta (householder). Here, a one leaves behind ones life in the world and retires to the forest (or serving the society), to live an ascetic life devoted to service, study of the scriptures and to meditation.
16. Antyeshti Samskara – The final sacrament, the funeral rites, are known as antyeshti Samskara.

https://www.astrojyoti.com/shodasimantra.htm

The above gives shaktha mantra.. but i dont know vaishnava equivalent of it for now this can be taken. Im not giving mantra here itself. because its mantra may cause harm if one chants without initiation.

As seen from the above all the kriyas end with Jiva that is the soul or self or atman.. it is this with this we need to infer that 15 types of worhsip is needed to know the self and in turn god. Jaisriram.

sri bharathiraman mukhya prana anthargatha sri krishnarpnamasthu.